# HTC Desire keeps restarting every 30 seconds

Tags: boot-loop, htc-desire, reboot

My HTC Desire is 2 years old. I have had numerous issues over the last 2 years between random freezing, unmounted SD card etc.. But now my phone will start, stay on for 30 seconds, and then shut down. It does this over and over. I have tried the safe mode. It does the same thing.  I tried Recovery Mode, to no avail. I have tried removing the battery for hours, no effect.  I did not recently update any apps.  I did not recently add any apps.  It literally began doing this out of nowhere in the middle of my day. I can access anything on the phone as long as it is within 30 seconds, then the phone restarts.

Comment: What did you try in recovery mode or does it restart even when in recovery mode? How good is your battery? Did you have the device plugged in when you tried out those solutions?